# jest doesn’t work with istanbul’s “html-spa” reporter

Tags: jestjs, istanbul

Jest (29.3.1) is supposed to work with all istanbul reporters:
https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/tree/master/packages/istanbul-reports/lib

But when I set the reporter to `html-spa` I get the error:

```
Error: Could not resolve a module for a custom reporter.
  Module name: html-spa
```

What am I missing?

**SOLVED**: Just a stilly mistake - I was using the `reporter` config key, **instead of `coverageReporter`**

Comment: As you did not attach anything, did you install the reporter?